# Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker: How to use date as a string and in a specific format

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

What I am trying to to do is when the user selects a specific date, to be able to use that date as a string, put it as data into a JSON object and retrieve data from the database as response.

Selecting the Day I want I am getting this in the console log:

```
Fri Sep 04 2015 16:15:24 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time)
```

And in order to use it I want to convert it into this:

```
20150904
```

I even used a directive but I suppose this is for a preview only.

```
.directive('datepickerPopup', function (){
return {
  restrict: 'EAC',
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function(scope, element, attr, controller) {
    //remove the default formatter from the input directive to prevent conflict
    controller.$formatters.shift();
  }
 }
});
```

Does anyone have a clue how this is going to be done? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this-

This is the sample code , you can try with your code -

```
angular.module('frontendApp')
    .controller('SearchCtrl',function ($scope, $filter) {

        $scope.formattedDate = $filter('date')($scope.date_of_birth, "dd/MM/yyyy");
        console.log('Formatted Date: ' + $scope.formattedDate);

    });
```

Replace, "$scope.date_of_birth" with your ng-model.

**Reference Links**

http://plnkr.co/edit/akLekgX7b1rcaMg6B9rI?p=preview

https://sonnguyen.ws/angularjs-datetime-format/

Comment: Hellon Aparna, is this in angular?

Comment: Actualy, i was also facing the same problem. Since, we were using the laravel framwork, the inputted date taken is in laravel format. In the above code, the input is taken from the request

Comment: Ok cause `->` symbol confused me

Comment: What is the backend and framework, that you are using?

Comment: I am using Java Jersey

Comment: @Margaret - I have edited my answer, Please check if that works for you. I have tried on my machine and it worked. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much Aparna that seems to work! The problem is that when the user picks another day it's not updated so I used $watch object. `$scope.$watch('dt', function() { $rootScope.formattedDate = $filter('date')($scope.dt, "yyyyMMdd"); console.log("Picked Date: " + $rootScope.formattedDate); }, true);` And now I can pass this value to another controller that calls the web service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple JavaScript for that and use it anywhere you feel fit(directive, filter, service etc.). Suppose 'date' contains your date. Here's the code:

```
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    month = month + 1;
    if(month < 10) {
        month = '0' + month;
    }
    var day = date.getDate();
    if(day < 10) {
        day = '0' + day;
    }
    date = year.toString() + month.toString() + day.toString();
    return date;
```

Comment: Hello Tarun, `$scope.dt` contains the selected day

Comment: It is not just a day it is a date. Just replace 'date' with '$scope.dt' in my code.

Comment: Tarun I can't get this to work, I assigned $scope.dt to a variable for example dateFormated and replaced it in your code into a directive but it's giving me a syntax error

Comment: Please create a plunker. Can't help you in this way.

Comment: oh indeed! It was working in my project though, give me a moment please

Comment: Unfortunately I can't make it to work, can you give me an example on how should I use it?